# Async Download and Deserialize

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.android

Good evening,

I am trying to refine some code using async programming and would like to know if the following code is well written or not, and if is there any way to improve it.

Its purpose is to download some JSON from a given URL and deserialize it to an object.

I have three (now four) questions (**and 1 issue described at the end of the post**):

- Should I use `TaskEx.Run` to run
  `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` ?
- Is there any good way (without checking the object properties) to
  know if `rootObject` was successfully created?
- Should I check somewhere whether Cancellation was requested or not?
- (**new question**) Should I CancelPendingRequests before doing a new request?

Without further ado, here's the code:

```
internal static class WebUtilities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Downloads the page of the given url
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">url to download the page from</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">token to cancel the download</param>
    /// <returns>the page content</returns>
    internal static async Task<string> DownloadStringAsync(string url, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            // create Http Client and dispose of it even if exceptions are thrown (same as using finally statement)
            using (var client = new HttpClient() {Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)})
            {
                // should I always do this?
                client.CancelPendingRequests();

                // do request and dispose of it when done
                using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    // if response was successful (otherwise it will return null)
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        // return its content
                        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (ex is System.Net.Sockets.SocketException || 
                                    ex is InvalidOperationException || 
                                    ex is OperationCanceledException ||
                                    ex is System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException)
        {
            WriteLine("DownloadStringAsync task has been cancelled.");
            WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }

        // return null if response was unsuccessful
        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Downloads Json from a given url and attempts its deserialization to a given reference type (class)
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">the class to deserialize to</typeparam>
    /// <param name="url">url to download the json from</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">token to cancel the download</param>
    /// <returns>the deserialized object</returns>
    internal static async Task<T> DownloadJsonAndDeserialize<T>(string url, CancellationToken cancellationToken) where T : class, new()
    {
        // download json from the given url
        var jsonResponse = await DownloadStringAsync(url, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // if the response is invalid, no need to go further
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonResponse))
            // return a default constructor instance
            return new T();

        // try to deserialize
        try
        {
            // Deserialize json data to the given .NET object
            // Should I use TaskEx.Run here?
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonResponse);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (ex is JsonException)
        {
            WriteLine("Something went wrong while deserializing json to the given reference type.");
            WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        // return a default constructor instance
        return new T();
    }
}
```

And to call the code, one would do something like:

```
internal static async Task CallAsync()
    {
        RootObject root = null;

        using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)))
        {
            var token = cts.Token;

            root = await WebUtilities.DownloadJsonAndDeserialize<RootObject>(URL, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        // do something with rootObject
        // any good way to know if rootObject was successfully created, before moving on?
    }
```

What would you change? and why?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

- Suggested by @codran - Every `await` is now using `ConfigureAwait(false)`
- `CancellationTokenSource` is now disposed of (using statement)
- Suggested by @codran - Some exceptions are now filtered
- `DownloadStringAsync` has now 2 `using` statements inside a `try-catch`
  block for more readability (instead of a `try-catch-finally`).
- Now checking if response `IsSuccessStatusCode`

**Issue found (created another question for it - [Timeouts in Xamarin HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382181/timeouts-in-xamarin-http-requests)):**

Interestingly enough, when a **host cannot be reached** (e.g., an offline local server), **nothing happens** after `GetAsync`. **After several minutes (around 3)** a `System.Net.WebException` is thrown saying **Error: ConnectFailure (Connection timed out)**. The Inner exception is `System.Net.Sockets.SocketsException` (full log here: http://pastebin.com/MzHyp2FM).

I have tried to set `client.Timeout` to 5 seconds **but that doesn't seem to work**.

Could be a Xamarin bug, though (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5941/system-net-http-httpclient-timeout-seems-to-be-ignored).

Either way, **shouldn't cancellationToken cancel automatically after 10 seconds**?

**This timeout issue happens with/when:**

- An offline/unreachable IP address (in my case an
  offline local server such as 192.168.1.101:8080) is requested (e.g., GetAsync, SendAsync, GetResponseAsync)

**The code works well with/when:**

- There is no Internet Connection (throws an exception)
- DNS cannot resolve the URL (throws an exception)
- A valid URL (up and running) is given
- The request is **made from a desktop client** (e.g., WPF), where if the
  IP is offline/unreachable it throws 4 exceptions really fast (**No
  connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
  it**)

**Conclusions**

- Xamarin seems to have some bugs in these requests (with Timeouts at
  least?), as they do not give the expected results otherwise seen in
  desktop applications.

Comment: `HttpClient.Timeout` and the `CancellationToken` should both work as you expect. Most likely bugs with Xamarin (I've seen *many* with their async and parallel support). Xamarin is in the process to moving to .NET Core, which should tremendously improve their reliability and correctness. IMO. :)

Comment: Thanks for stopping by @StephenCleary! Unfortunately, that seems to be the case (since 2012 or 2013?). Anything else I could improve? How about my first question?

Comment: No, I wouldn't use `Task.Run` for JSON deserialization. Unless your objects are *massive*, they should deserialize quickly, and even if they *are* massive, `Task.Run` would belong at the UI level, not in a `WebUtilities` module.

Comment: @StephenCleary Makes total sense. I asked because I have seen some examples using Task.RunEx for JSON deserialization. FYI, just updated the main post with some test results... Seems it's really a bug in Xamarin, as it works perfectly in a desktop client app. I'm really sad... but happy the code *works*. What can I do?

Comment: You could try using `HttpWebRequest`, but I'm not sure if the timeout/cancellation support works there, either.

Comment: Doesn't work either. Still having a 3 minute timeout.

Comment: @StephenCleary Should I create another StackOverflow question with only this issue in mind?

Comment: Sure, just specifically about timeouts for Xamarin HTTP requests.

Comment: Done - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382181/timeouts-in-xamarin-http-requests

Answer (score 2):

> Should I use `TaskEx.Run` to run `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>`?

Throwing the JSON deserialisation onto another thread likely won't achieve anything. You're freeing up the current thread but then need to wait for your work to be scheduled on another thread. Unless you need Newtonsoft.Json APIs specifically, consider using [`ReadAsAsync<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontentextensions.readasasync(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync%60%601%28System.Net.Http.HttpContent%29). You can use that with a [`JsonMediaTypeFormatter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.jsonmediatypeformatter(v=vs.118).aspx), which [uses Newtonsoft.Json internally anyway](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/JsonMediaTypeFormatter.cs).

> Is there any good way (without checking the object properties) to know if rootObject was successfully created?

You need to define what success looks like. For example, your JSON could be `null`, so `rootObject` is null. Or it could be missing properties, or your JSON has extra properties that were not deserialised. I don't think there's a way to fail the serialisation for excess or missing properties, so you would have to check that yourself. I could be wrong on this point.

> Should I check somewhere whether Cancellation was requested or not?

You need to see what makes sense in your code and when it is being cancelled. For example, there's no point acting on the cancellation token as the very last line in your function, when all the work has been completed.

Does it make sense for your application to cancel the operation if the JSON has been downloaded, but not yet deserialised? Does it make sense for your application to cancel the operation if the JSON has been deserialised, but the object graph has not yet been validation (question 2)?

It really depends on your needs, but I'd probably cancel if the download has not yet completed - which it seems that you are already doing - but once the download is completed, that is the point of no return.

> What would you change? and why?

Use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on the Tasks that you `await`. This prevents deadlocks if your code ever blocks and waits for the resulting Task (e.g. `.Wait()` or `.Result`).

Use `using` blocks instead of `try`-`finally`.

Comment: **1st question** - Not entirely sure I can replace it by ReadAsAsync, but I will certainly take a look!
**2nd question** - I guess checking for null and some specific properties should suffice then.
**3rd question** - I already check if DownloadStringAsync return isn't null or string.Empty (which would mean something failed. Either no internet connection or Task was cancelled)

**Changes and why** - Totally forgot about ConfigureAwait(false)... using blocks instead of try - finally? what if there's an exception within that block? That is the reason I changed into one.

Comment: One more thing - don't catch `Exception`. Catch specific subclasses, e.g. `OperationCanceledException`.

Comment: I also thought about it, but I am not entirely sure about what exceptions might be thrown. Should I catch the ones I know first? and at the end catch exception?

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(false)` is not a panacea, is often the wrong thing to use, and certainly is not a solution to deadlocks. The answer to deadlocks is to not have threads waiting on multiple locks taken in different orders.

Comment: True. GetAsync is still hanging when the host isn't reachable. Any ideas?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I've found to be usually-right-except-for-UI-functions. Also, deadlocks aren't always lock-related. If the scheduler is waiting for a thread, which is in turn waiting for the scheduled Task, there's no explicit lock involved but there is a deadlock.

Comment: @Apidcloud `TaskCanceledException` is a subclass of `OperationCanceledException`. You don't need to catch both in this case. `GetAsync` shouldn't hang indefinitely, IIRC there's a default timeout of 60 seconds. What do you define as "not reachable"? There are a variety of failure types that could cause a connection to fail.

Comment: @Apidcloud you only ever catch exceptions that are expected and which you have a more specific method of handling in this context than allowing the exception handler to take over. You *want* unforeseen exceptions to bubble up higher to the exception handler so that it can log the exception, notify you, and stop code from continuing and making an incorrect assumption and wrecking something important.

Comment: @codran Thanks! Regarding the issue... I just stopped my local server (the host I download the Json from) and tried to run the app. Nothing happens after GetAsync... setting a client timeout doesn't seem to work either. Ideally, it would go back to the call as an empty object.

Comment: @jnm2 Thanks! I am trying to do so with filters now :)

Comment: @codran After several minutes a System.Net.WebException was thrown - connection time out. Setting HttpClient.Timeout doesn't to help though.

Comment: _"deadlocks aren't always lock-related"_ -- they are, as long as you don't use the word "lock" too literally. Deadlock happens when multiple resources are in contention and acquired in different orders. The word "lock" is usually sufficient for most people to understand that this applies to _any_ resource that can be acquired exclusively, and simplifies discussions pertaining to deadLOCK.

Comment: `Throwing the JSON deserialisation onto another thread likely won't achieve anything. You're freeing up the current thread but then need to wait for your work to be scheduled on another thread` This is totally wrong, await is not wait for !!!

Comment: @AkashKava care to elaborate? The user still needs to wait for that work to be scheduled and to run, regardless of what thread or synchronisation context the work is done on.

Comment: @codran wait? Do you know difference between wait and await?

Comment: @AkashKava Yes, I do. Would you care to elaborate, rather than just asking counter-questions?

Comment: @codran Your statement says that there is no benefit of doing JSON deserialization on another thread, if you do it on main thread (UI thread), it freezes UI, why would you want to do that? If it is done on background thread, we will just show spinner indicating some activity is on and when result arrives, we will display. Also MediaTypeFormatter is crap, it deserializes everything on main thread, https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/Formatting/BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.cs#L174 , checkout.

Comment: @codran also `aspnetwebstack` was designed for ASP.NET, not UI applications, anyways, you can try couple of samples in UI thread to see what is better.

Comment: @AkashKava That depends on whether or not you return to the UI thread after the download is complete - with `ConfigureAwait(false)` there is very little (zero?) chance of that. The deserialisation would typically happen on whatever thread the previous async operation finished on, which would be a background thread. And depending on the size of your JSON, doing it on the UI thread may not even be an issue. Furthermore, MediaTypeFormatter performs the work on whatever thread the task was scheduled on. This is in no way, shape or form guaranteed to be the UI thread, as above.

Answer (score 0):

I am using following code in production without any issues.

```
// Creating and disposing HttpClient is unnecessary
// if you are going to use it multiple time
// reusing HttpClient improves performance !!
// do not worry about memory leak, HttpClient
// is designed to close resources used in single "SendAsync"
// method call
private static HttpClient client;


public Task<T> DownloadAs<T>(string url){

    // I know I am firing this on another thread
    // to keep UI free from any smallest task like
    // preparing httpclient, setting headers
    // checking for result or anything..., why do that on
    // UI Thread?

    // this helps us using excessive logging required for
    // debugging and diagnostics

    return Task.Run(async ()=> {

       // following parses url and makes sure
       // it is a valid url
       // there is no need for this to be done on 
       // UI thread
       Uri uri = new Uri(url);

       HttpRequestMessage request = 
          new HttpRequestMessage(uri,HttpMethod.Get);

       // do some checks, set some headers...
       // secrete code !!!

       var response = await client.SendAsync(request,
           HttpCompletionOption.ReadHeaders);

       string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

       if(((int)response.StatusCode)>300){

           // it is good to receive error text details
           // not just reason phrase

           throw new InvalidOperationException(response.ReasonPhrase  
              + "\r\n" + content);
       }
       return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content);

    });
}
```

ConfigureAwait is tricky, and makes debugging more complicated. This code will run without any issues.

If you want to use `CancellationToken` then you can pass your token in `client.GetAsync` method.

Comment: Any reason to not use `client.GetAsync` and `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync`?

Comment: @Apidcloud sorry, it was typo, added `GetAsync`

Comment: I am still trying to make your code work. `HttpRequestMessage` constructor should have `uri` as 2nd argument. But `GetAsync` doesn't seem to have a `HttpRequestMessage` overload.

Comment: If I use GetAsync(uri, cancellationToken) it still takes about 3 minutes to throw the mentioned exception.

Comment: Noticed you have changed to SendAsync, but the timeout issue remains. Setting client.Timeout doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is it only problem in iOS or on Android as well?

Comment: My tests are done on Xamarin Android, but I have read it also happens with iOS.

Comment: I haven't faced any problems with timeout, connection failure occurs quite immediately, less than a minute in my app. But I have not set any explicit timeout anywhere, I just run with default. Is this Emulator related problem or on physical device?

Comment: I tried with both an emulator and a real device. The timeout is around 3 minutes