# Timeouts in Xamarin HTTP requests

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous, xamarin.android

Good evening!

I was trying to clean/refine some code and ended up finding issues with **timeouts in Xamarin HTTP requests** (as described in my original thread: [Async Download and Deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369180/async-download-and-deserialize)).

**Issue found (only tested with Xamarin.Android; don't know about iOS):**

When a **host cannot be reached** (e.g., an offline local server), `GetAsync` throws a `System.Net.WebException` after roughly **3 minutes** with the message **Error: ConnectFailure (Connection timed out)**. The Inner exception is `System.Net.Sockets.SocketsException` (full log here: http://pastebin.com/MzHyp2FM).

**Code:**

```
internal static class WebUtilities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Downloads the page of the given url
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="url">url to download the page from</param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken">token to cancel the download</param>
    /// <returns>the page content or null when impossible</returns>
    internal static async Task<string> DownloadStringAsync(string url, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            // create Http Client and dispose of it even if exceptions are thrown (same as using finally statement)
            using (var client = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) })
            {
                // should I always do this?
                client.CancelPendingRequests();

                // Issue here; Timeout of roughly 3 minutes
                using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    // if response was successful (otherwise return null)
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        // return its content
                        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // TODO: split exceptions?
        catch (Exception ex) when (ex is System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ||
                                    ex is InvalidOperationException ||
                                    ex is OperationCanceledException ||
                                    ex is System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException)
        {
            WriteLine("DownloadStringAsync task has been cancelled.");
            WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }

        // return null if response was unsuccessful
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Calling Method:**

```
internal static async Task CallAsync(string url)
    {
        using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)))
        {
            var token = cts.Token;
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            string result = await WebUtilities.DownloadStringAsync(url, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

**Setting `client.Timeout` doesn't seem to work.**

Either way, **shouldn't cancellationToken cancel automatically after 10 seconds**?

**This timeout issue happens when:**

- An offline/unreachable IP address (in my case an offline local server
  such as 192.168.1.101:8080) is requested (i.e., using `GetAsync`, `SendAsync`,
  `GetResponseAsync`)

**The code works well when:**

- The request is made from a **desktop client** (e.g., **WPF**). If the
  IP is offline/unreachable it throws 4 exceptions really fast (**No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**).

**Conclusions**

Xamarin seems to have some **bugs in Http requests** (with Timeouts at least?), as they do not give the expected results. And from what I have read, it could be something that has been around for few a years (since 2012 or 2013).

Xamarin unit testing doesn't really help either: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/1b3a76c6874853049e89bbc113b22bc632ed5ca4/src/Mono.Android/Test/Xamarin.Android.Net/HttpClientIntegrationTests.cs

**Edit**

- `Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)` - works
- `Timeout = Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)` - doesn't work (?????)
- `Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000)` (and above) - doesn't
  work

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Just for a quick test, can you try `modernhttpclient xamarin` https://components.xamarin.com/view/modernhttpclient? It uses different stack and if you get different result then there may be a bug in HttpClient.

Comment: Tested their Android sample (in a real device with Android 4.2), but it still has a 3 minute timeout (when using an offline local server). They still use `HttpClient`, even though they create its instance with a `NativeMessageHandler`.

Comment: @CodeOverFlow I am still using Task.Delay instead of cancellation token. I haven't had the time to check if they fixed the bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that that changing the http client settings for Android resolved my issue.
To solve the issue:

- from `HttpClient` implementation to `AndroidClientHandler`
- from **SSL/TLS** implementation to **Native TLS 1.2+**

In Xamarin Android project options. "Default" values were using Mono's own client which caused the problem.

I posted more details [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20181205205745/http://jeremei.com/xamarinvisual-studio-httpclient-request-timeout/).

Comment: 1/10 of my web requests fail with connection timeout and this happens only in production environment. Do you think changing the http client from default to Android Native will solve the issue? Shouldn't all web requests, and not only part of them, fail if problem is in TLS implementation?